# Is there known integer polynomial $f(p,q)$ for which $(p-q)!=p!-q!+f(p,q)$?

Tags: number-theory, factorial, gamma-function

let $p, q$ be prime number such that $p >q$ and $f$ be integer polynomial  such that :$f:\mathbb{N\times N}\to \mathbb{N}$ , I invesitagted in the web to find such integer polynomial for which: $f(p,q)$ for which $(p-q)!=p!-q!+f(p,q)$  but I didn't got , I have used properties of gamma function by means functional function satisfied by Gamma but I can't up to the disered function $f(p,q)$, Any help ?

Comment: Fixing $q=2$ we'd get that the polynomial $g(p)=f(p,2)=(p-2)!-p!+2=(p-2)!(1-p(p-1))+2$ but that function grows faster (in absolute value) than any polynomial.

Comment: But what you have got is not polynomial , your function looks like you did : 5=7+x implies x=5-7 , I want for example if I have 2 arbitrary prime p=7, q=3 how I can write (7-3)! using 7!-3! add some suitable polynomial for which this identity hold

Comment: I don't understand.  What I wrote shows that $f(p,q)$ can not be a polynomial.

Comment: Do u meant there  is no polynomial  f(p,q) ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.